# Java programming test for interview

Tags: java, oop

Here is a programming test used in a job interview. I find it has a very strange non-OO perspective and wonder why anyone would approach a constructor from this perspective. As a very experienced Java programmer, I immediately question the ability of the individual who wrote this code and the strange perspective of the question.

I find these strange out of context questions on interviews disturbing. I would love feedback from other experienced OO Java programmers.

> Complete the Solver constructor so that a call to solveAll return a list with 2 values
>   including the square root and the inverse of the integer passed as parameter.

```
public interface MathFunction {
    double calculate(double x);
}

public class Solver {

    private List<MathFunction> functionList;

    public Solver() { 

        //Complete here

    }

    public List<Double> solveAll(double x) {
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (MathFunction function : this.functionList) {
            result.add(new Double(function.calculate(x)));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find this strange or non-OO. But then again, I am not very experienced and am looking forward to some answers. ;)

Comment: Do we need a new [I'm currently in an interview on my iPhone] tag to rival [homework]? :-)

Comment: I often find interview question disturbing, but finding good interview questions is hard, so I wouldn't read too much into the technical questions. In real programs you will find things which are not the way you would have done them, so this sort of question can be good in determining how the candidate would handle that situation. ;)

Comment: You should insist that you want feedback on the programming test, not answer to it... some people seems to not understand :)

Comment: I think the point of this is to ensure that the interviewee does not attempt to call `solveAll` within the constructor. They simply want to see that you understand the code, and the fact that you manage to figure out that what you need to do is to create two `MathFunction` implementations and store them in the list so that they can be used at a later time by the `solveAll` method.

Comment: Why does the question say that an `integer` is (to be) passed as parameter?

Comment: It's a warning that your potential employer does not find code like this that alarming and is possibly quite common in the codebase they will have you maintain. run! before it's too late!

Answer (score 38):

This is testing your design patterns, by using the simplest possible method. I think this could be the Strategy (or some other behavioural pattern). See these:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern

If you are going for a Java interview, you should be able to identify the design pattern they are hinting at and that should prevent you from being too unsettled!

To answer the question, create two classes that implement `MathFunction` as required, then create two instances and store them in `functionList`.

The point here is *not* 'can you do calculations in this strange way', it is 'can you identify design patterns'.

Comment: You've only gone and given him the answer! ;-)

Comment: Nooo Joe! Put Strategy back. It's more of a Strategy than a Template

Comment: @jeff - I put strategy back but it does look like template? I dunno it's been a couple of years since I thought about them by name

Comment: @DuncanJones - I assume the interview's over!

Comment: I've interviewed someone before and given them a question they couldn't quite get. It's cruel not to explain the question afterwards otherwise people don't improve.

Comment: I don't understand where you see a template method pattern

Answer (score 31):

I agree that it's confusing and over-engineered.

But I do think the code is reasonably object-oriented. It's an instance of the strategy pattern. The code that generates a *list* of answers doesn't care how the answers are calculated - the two concerns are separated and a different calculation strategy could be applied without having to touch the code that generates the list.

To make the class more useful, these functions should be passed in from the outside (i.e. dependency injection) rather than being instantiated in the constructor.

You know the answer, I assume, but for what it's worth...

```
public Solver() {
    functionList = new ArrayList<MathFunction>();

    functionList.add(new MathFunction() {

        @Override
        public double calculate(double x) {
            return 1d/x;
        }
    });

    functionList.add(new MathFunction() {

        @Override
        public double calculate(double x) {
            return Math.sqrt(x);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: A programmer could of spent the last 10 years using and coding factory patterns, strategy patterns, template patterns and implementing many inner classes and interfaces for many reasons.  The programming question is not designed to find that out especially if it is a timed question.  I need a rational perspective and context otherwise it is a silly exercise that leaves everyone guessing.

Comment: If I was in an interview I wouldn't argue "this is stupid it wouldn't ever come up in real life", I would get on with it and discuss it afterwards.

Comment: If I were giving a question like this on a test, I'd be looking for the recognition of the better answer and an exposition as to why this way is better than the other.  I always found the _discussion_ of the questions and answers to be far more useful than the answers the interviewee responded with.

Comment: It's been a while since I last touched Java code, can you instantiate an interface like this these days? Pretty cool if so!

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, it is indeed a strange approach. The name `Solver` is generic, it shouldn't implement specific operations by default. However, maybe that was part of the interview? Part one: simply fulfill the request. Part two: say that it is strange to do so.

I would say that a much nicer approach would be to have an `addMathFunction(MathFunction mf)` method. And if wanted, to create subclasses that extend the `Solver` class and add MathFunctions in their constructor.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that this probably isn't the best way, or most OO way to do this, I would have to assume that the point of this exercise is to see how well you understand Inheritance, Interfaces and maybe anonymous inner classes. That's the only thing I can figure.

Comment: As @Joe points out in his answer, the other thing that this question is looking for, is to see if you can recognize the design pattern and implement it correctly.

Comment: The request to complete the constructor so that method x returns y is what initially throws me off.  After analysis of what is there you can get the gist of what you can do.  Use the MathFunction interface to implement 2 functions via inner classes.  It is like a strategy pattern/template pattern/factory pattern but not quite.

Answer (score 3):

I think they wanted you to add two items in the functionlist. Each one would implement the MathFunction interface, one for the square root and one for the inverse.
The prboblem lies in the details:

1- You have a function which returns 2 values because it does two different things, that is bad

2-  If you want to have this "do-it-all" class,m it would be interesting to receive the Mathfunctions as a parameter so you can do any sort of MathFunctions, the MathFunctions would be parameterizable

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution.  This is a simple illustration of a [factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

```
public Solver() { 
    functionList = new ArrayList<MathFunction>();
    MathFunction sqrt = new MathFunction() {
        @Override
        public double calculate(double x) {
            return Math.sqrt(x);
        }

    };
    functionList.add(sqrt);
    MathFunction inverse = new MathFunction() {
        @Override
        public double calculate(double x) {
            return 1.0D / x;
        }

    };
    functionList.add(inverse);
}
```

This question shows two things:

- Whether the programmer understands math terms like inverse.
- Whether the programmer understands that instances of interfaces or classes can be stored in a list, and iterated over later.

Comment: Another one who didn't read the question... The OP definitely knows how to do it.

Comment: I explained what it was and (finally) provided a link to an explanation.

Comment: Actually, at least one of the "solutions" should be kept here. Because there might be some guys that don't know the answer and they might find one here and therefore might understand the "real" answers to this question better...

Comment: Where is the the factory method pattern ?

Comment: @brimborium may be, a solution should have been provided in the question.

Comment: @gontard: The factory is defined in the constructor and used in the solveAll method.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc sorry, but I do not see the factory pattern here. "Like other creational patterns, it deals with the problem of creating objects (products) without specifying the exact class of object that will be created." You are simply instantiating an anonymous class and using it. Strategy would fit better here IMHO

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I coded the solution to my own question.  My instinct that nothing should be in the constructor seems to be correct.  The functionList is not static so you need an instance to initialize it.  It specifies integer so I round to integer.  The inverse function is not advanced math in any way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Solver {

    private List<MathFunction> functionList = new ArrayList<MathFunction>();;

    public Solver() { 

// Complete here

    }

    public void initFunctionList() {

        MathFunction functionSquareRoot = new MathFunction(){

            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) {
                return (x<0 ? 0: Math.sqrt(x));  // maybe we need throw an exception here for negative numbers, but we'll just set it to 0
            }};

        MathFunction functionInverse = new MathFunction(){

            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) {
                return (x!=0.0 ? 1/x : 0);
            }

        };

        functionList.add(functionSquareRoot);
        functionList.add(functionInverse);

    }

    public List<Double> solveAll(double x) {
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for (MathFunction function : this.functionList) {
            result.add(new Double(function.calculate(x)));
        }

        return result;
    }

}


public interface MathFunction {
     double calculate(double x);
}


public class TestSolver {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solver s = new Solver();
        s.initFunctionList();
        System.out.println(s.solveAll(16.0));

    }

}
```

I mislead myself the constructor can be

```
public Solver() { 

// Complete here
        MathFunction functionSquareRoot = new MathFunction(){

            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) {
                return (x<0 ? 0: Math.sqrt(x));  // maybe we need throw an exception here for negative numbers, but we'll just set it to 0
            }};

        MathFunction functionInverse = new MathFunction(){

            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) {
                return (x!=0.0 ? 1/x : 0);
            }

        };

        functionList.add(functionSquareRoot);
        functionList.add(functionInverse);

    }
```

Comment: why bother with the rounding?  Just wondering if there's any particular reason.

Comment: @MartyE, the question says 'integer', so rounding is "needed"

Comment: @bestsss It still seems like you wouldn't want to round here.  If anything, you would want to change `double calculate(double x);` to `double calculate(int x);` then convert x to a `double`.

Comment: Just asking, with this, don't you risk the `1/x1` with an `int` divided by a `long` resulting in `0` because of the rounding on `int`/`long` types?  I don't have a Java compiler here to test with, so I am truly asking.

Comment: @MartyE, you work within the conditions given by the interviewer, i.e. double->double and stating integer. The wording is not smart and perhaps unintended but it's ok. If it's an integer division by zero it is an error and shall not be handled explicitly, imo. There is no rounding in `int/long` the int is promoted to long. Java has not bytecodes that operate on mixed types (it's either int:int or long:long). Also `double` can hold all `int` values w/o rounding error.

Comment: @bestsss So in Java, is the `long/long` return the "rounded `long`" or does it convert that to a `double` or `float`?  If it's not converted, then the rounding would result in either `0` or `1`, correct? (ex: `1/1 == 1` and `1/3 == 0` (with remainder 1)).

Comment: @user916115 also, the inverse of a negative is still legitimately `1/x`.

Comment: @MartyE, long/long is an integer division, i.e 1/3==0 (the remainder is 2, though). The result is converted to double (implicitly) to return the result of the function. Again, imo if stating integer, it shall be an integer division.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat contrived, seems closer to the decorator pattern to me.
Not sure what I would say during an interview but here is how I would code it:

```
package math;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DecoratorMath 
{

    interface MathFunction 
    {
        double calculate(double x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DecoratorMath decoratorMath =  new DecoratorMath();
        decoratorMath.go();
    }

    public void go() 
    {
        Solver solver = new Solver();
        decorate(solver);
        List<Double> results = solver.solveAll(02);
        for (Double d :results) 
        {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    public void decorate(Solver solver)
    {
        solver.addFunction(new MathFunction() 
        {
            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) 
            {
                return Math.sqrt(x);
            }
        });

        solver.addFunction(new MathFunction() 
        {
            @Override
            public double calculate(double x) 
            {
                return 1d/x;
            }
        });
    }

    class Solver
    {
        private List<MathFunction> mathFunctions = new ArrayList<MathFunction>();

        public void addFunction(MathFunction mathFunction)
        {
            mathFunctions.add(mathFunction);
        }

        public List<Double> solveAll(double x) 
        {
            List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for (MathFunction function : mathFunctions) 
            {
                result.add(new Double(function.calculate(x)));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this all within the Constructor is just poor practice. Anyway my all-in-one solution.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

//sqrt / inverse

public class Solver{

  private List<MathFunction> functionList;

  public interface MathFunction{
     double calculate(double x);
  }

  class X implements MathFunction {
    public double calculate(double x) {
      return Math.sqrt(x); 
  } 
  }

    class Y implements MathFunction {
    public double calculate(double y) {
      return 1/y; 
  } 
  }



  public Solver(){
  //here
    functionList = new ArrayList<MathFunction>();

    MathFunction f =  (MathFunction) new X();
    functionList.add(f);  

    MathFunction f2 =  (MathFunction) new Y();
    functionList.add(f2);

  }


  public List<Double> solveAll(double x){ 

  List<Double> result=new ArrayList<Double>();

    for (MathFunction function : this.functionList){

      result.add(new Double(function.calculate(x)));

    }

    return result;

  }

public static void main(String... args) {

    System.out.println("result="+new Solver().solveAll(123));

}

}
```